# Linq to entities - reusing predicates with navigation properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am trying to find a way to reuse predicates for filtering entities in EF 6.1.3. I've run into a problem filtering related properties using 'Where'.

E.g. if I have this interface `IValidFromTo`

```
public interface IValidFromTo
{
   DateTime StartDate { get; set;}
   DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

and a function that returns a predicate for `Where` :

```
public class Extensions 
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Current<T>() 
  where T : IValidFromTo
  {
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now; 
    return x => x.StartDate <= currentDate && x.EndDate >= currentDate;
  } 
}
```

See http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx for background.

When applied directly to DbSet, this method works.

```
var query = ctx.Items.Where(Extensions.Current<Item>()); // compiles
```

But how to make it work with a more complex query dealing with navigation properties?

E.g. if I have a `DbSet<Person>` with a collection of `Item`:

```
public class Person
{
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to project it into an object containing the name of the person and just the current `Items`, I end up with some rather cluttered code:

```
var relationQuery = ctx.People.Select(x => new 
    { Name = x.Name,
      CurrentItems = x.Items.AsQueryable().Where(Extensions.Current<Item>())
    });
```

I wonder if it is possible to improve this code, e.g. to be able to write something like

```
CurrentItems = x.Items.Current() // quasi an extension method on `ICollection<Item>`?
```

(writing an extension method on `ICollection<IValidFromTo>` doesn't work, because EFf wouldn't recognize this method and throw an error)

**UPDATE**

Seems like this is achievable via a `Join` (supposing that each `Person` can only have a single valid item):

```
var isCurrent= x => <<some condition on x>>;
...  
var validItems = ctx.Items.Where(isCurrent);
var peopleWithCurrentItems = from person in ctx.Persons
                                join item in validItems on person.Id equals item.Owner.Id
                                select new { Person = person, Item = item };
```

If there may be more than one valid `Item` per `Person`, then

```
var grouped = peopleWithValid.GroupBy(x => x.Person);
```

However, this version of the query will exclude persons with no matching `Items`.